# checking to see if a phrase without underscores is an isogram in java

Tags: java

```
class IsogramChecker {

    boolean isIsogram(String phrase) {
        if (phrase == null)
            return false;
        phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();
        char phraseArray [] = phrase.toCharArray();
        for (char ch:phraseArray)
            if (ch == '-')
                return true;
            else if (ch == ' ')
                return true;
            else if (ch == '_' & ch == ' ' || ch == '-')
                return true;
            else if (phrase.indexOf(ch) != phrase.lastIndexOf(ch))
                return false;
        return true;
        // return phrase.length() == phrase.toLowerCase().chars().distinct().count();
    }

}
```

This code arrangement passed all every test cases with the exception of

```
testIsogramWithDuplicatedCharAfterHyphen() {
    assertThat(isogramChecker.isIsogram("thumbscrew-jappingly")).isFalse();
}
```

Can someone help explain this?

Comment: What is your logical reason for returning true as soon as you reach a `'-'`, `' '`? You can't just treat every String as an isogram as soon as you find one of those characters. And what do you intend to do with the line `else if (ch == '_' & ch == ' '  ....`. how can a character be `'_'` and  `' '` at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

**isogram** = every char occurs only once (with the exception of the irrelevant space, hyphen and underscore).

The problem is that you return true on the first irrelevant char in the *for* loop.

Some minor things:

- In java the type is kept together, without the variable in the middle.
  For backward C/C++ compatibility you may write `char x[10];` but you will always encounter only `char[] x;`.
- `&` must be `&&` and was a bit misplaced there.
- The pattern `CASE_A && CASE_B && CASE_C` is always wrong: at least one of the cases is false, hence the entire expression is false. A negation for every case is missing.

So

```
boolean isIsogram(String phrase) {
    if (phrase == null)
        return false;
    phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();
    char[] phraseArray = phrase.toCharArray();
    for (char ch:phraseArray) {
        if (ch != '_' && ch != ' ' && ch != '-') {
            if (phrase.indexOf(ch) != phrase.lastIndexOf(ch)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And your Stream version:

```
    phrase = phrase.replaceAll("[-_ ]", "");
    return phrase.length() == phrase.toLowerCase().chars().distinct().count();
```

For Chinese and such you might want to use `codePoints` instead of `chars`:

```
    return phrase.toLowerCase().codePoints().count()
        == phrase.toLowerCase().codePoints().distinct().count();
```

And there are languages where the (defaulted) Locale gives other character lengths. In German the uppercase of `ß` is `SS`.

Comment: The third version with Unicode code points of course also needs its irrelevant interpunction removed with `replaceAll`. Good that it works.

Comment: But isnt "Otto" also an isogram? I thought an isogram is a word where all characters occur the same often

Comment: [Isogram or heterogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterogram_(literature)#Isograms) is something else. The code with indexOf and lastIndexOf is indeed misleading, also to me at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and my code passes the test:

```java
import java.util.*;

class IsogramChecker {
    boolean isIsogram(String phrase) {
        if (phrase == null) return false;

        phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();
        // Key is the character, value is equivalent to the amount of occurenses
        // E.g.: Otto -> {"o": 2, "t": 2}
        HashMap<Character, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
        
        // Count the occurences of all characters
        for (char c : phrase.toCharArray()) {
            if (counter.containsKey(c)) {
                counter.put(c, counter.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                counter.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(counter.values());
        
        // Check if all characters occur the same amount of time
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (i != list.size() - 1 && list.get(i) != list.get(i + 1)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually met this implementation style but I had hard times understanding it.

Comment: Think my understanding level with java is still to low. I'll will deepen my knowledge in the area and try you style too. Thanks!